# Are there Secure Coding Standards other that CERT?

Tags: secure-coding, standards

I am familiar with the CERT Secure Coding Standart. Are there also any other secure coding standarts other than the CERT ones?

Comment: We do expect you to do some of your own research here.  Spend some time browsing through the first couple of pages of results of a search for "secure coding standards" and you'll find plenty of references to others.

Comment: Easy @Xander. Welcome to security.SE Exagon! You've asked a fair and honest question, however we've found that questions asking for recommendation of reading lists tend to devolve into people arguing about their personal preferences, and therefore are not a great fit for the question-answer format. Because of that, we're going to close your question. If you can think of a way to re-phrase it that's less opinion / list based, then please [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/119880/edit).

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of two:

- The [OWASP Developer Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Guide_Project) (to go along with the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)).
- [David A. Wheeler's Secure Programming HOWTO](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO.html), which is a very long and very comprehensive guide.